# Could not initialize class java.util.logging.LogManager Exception starting JBoss

Tags: java, logging, jboss

Launching JBoss 7.0 Runtime Server from Eclipse. Web app deployed on server.  Getting following error message on JBoss startup:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.jboss.logmanager.LoggerNode.<init>(LoggerNode.java:104)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext.<init>(LogContext.java:47)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext.<clinit>(LogContext.java:41)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:104)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:51)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at      sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:498)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:167)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:156)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:275)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:229)
at java.util.logging.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:181)
... 17 more
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.util.logging.LogManager
at java.util.logging.LogManager$Cleaner.run(LogManager.java:199)
```

Where should I look to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like permission problem.

Most of the chances that there is a problem with ClassLoader. When you launch from Eclipse, it has custom class loader. Maybe you should provide some extra configuration parameter or maybe change some existing configuration that accidentally works with standalone JBoss, but doesn't works in another class loading environments.
You should post your code and configuration data to improve answers quality.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a problem with the JBOSS permissions.

Comment: what do you mean?  I can run JBoss standalone fine without errors.  Only when I try to start it from Eclipse then I run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrey that this looks like a ClassLoader problem. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1547 describing what happens with a ServiceWrapper. Then see http://community.chrononsystems.com/chronon_systems/topics/cannot_record_jboss_as7_via_ide for what happens with an agent.  Both are just like the problem with Eclipse described here.

In all three cases, there is something else that initializes the java logger first, before JBoss gets to it.  When JBoss tries it just quits.  Here's the offending code... http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.logmanager/jboss-logmanager/1.2.0.GA/org/jboss/logmanager/Logger.java#Logger.

Not sure if there's a way to fix this, but I'm definitely having this problem.